# My Ad is not running due to "Limited by budget" issue

Tags: google-ads, youtube

My Ad is not running due to "Limited by budget" issue.

I'm running a YouTube's video campaign to promote my video. When I was started it was working absolutely fine with minimum budget by ₹100 only. But as 2-3 days passed Ads stopped ("Limited by budget") showing. And reason was the "Limited by budget" issue.

I haven't used any keywords to the advertising just few categories, age group and location!

Nowadays it is showing again-n-again which is so ridiculous. First time it suggested to raise daily budget by ₹850 so I did. Then after 1 day it appeared  again and asked to raise daily budget up to ₹3000. Well, I did again. And now, later 1 day it is suggesting me to raise my daily budget beyond ₹9K. How insane this is. How could I just keep following recommendation and keeping my wallet empty?

Comment: What bidding strategy do you have in place? What's your max CPV? "Limited by budget" means your ads could be shown more often than you have funds to pay for it. Either deal with with the warning, up your budget, refine your audience, or cut your CPV.